# momentjs toDate() date return not same as format() date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `moment 2.16.0` and want starting days of month. There are different result of `toDate()` and `format()` method. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evzcz58x/).

code:-

```
var time=moment().subtract(0,'months').startOf("month").format();
console.log(time); //2016-12-01T00:00:00+05:30

var time2=moment().subtract(0, 'months').endOf("month").format();
console.log(time2); //2016-12-31T23:59:59+05:30

var time=moment().subtract(0,'months').startOf("month").toISOString();
console.log(time); //2016-11-30T18:30:00.000Z  here i want somethings like 2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z


var time2=moment().subtract(0, 'months').endOf("month").toISOString();
console.log(time2); // 2016-12-31T18:29:59.999Z here i want somethings like 2016-12-31T59:59:59.000Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your operations are using moment with **local** time except the `toISOString`, which will give you the string in UTC. Since your timezone is offset from UTC, naturally the local time string (from `format`) and the UTC time string (from `toISOString`) are very different.

> here i want somethings like 2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z

That would be a different time from what that Moment instance represents.

If you want something in an ISO-8601 format **but** in local time, you can use `format` with the appropriate set of formatting tokens, but you don't wan the `Z` at the end because, again, you're not dealing with UTC ("Zulu") time, you're dealing with local time.

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS")
```